# Adding a new event with source property never displays?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having trouble adding events to fullCalendar when I specify a `source` parameter in the event I pass to `renderEvent` - what am I doing wrong?

If I specify a `source`, the event does not (ever) show on the calendar... Looking at [fullcalendar.js v2.3.2 line 9348](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/dist/fullcalendar.js#L9348) Could it be that the `cache.push(events)` is incorrectly placed in the `if` statement just above?

(The scenario here is that when I add new events, I want them to become part of a particular source, not fullCalendar's internal "sticky" source).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

You should not specify a source property. 
From [event object documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/):

> source:    Event Source Object. **Automatically populated**.
>
> A reference to the event source that this event came from

I've created a [plunker with very Basic fullCalendar 2.3.2 with creation of event with source](http://plnkr.co/edit/svfS2M?p=preview) when you can check how the source property works:

So if you define an event like:

```js
{
    title : 'mytitle',
    start : moment(),
    allDay: false,
    id: 1,
    description: 'my event from source'
}
```

You can check, in the console of the plunkr, that the event receives a Source property, automatically populated, with the content:

```js
event.source 
{
    events: Array[1], 
    className: Array[0], 
    origArray: Array[1]
}
```

## Proposed solution

So for your goal you should define your events as items in an array source:

```js
   var mySource1 = [{
            title : 'Source 1',
            start : moment(),
            allDay: false,
            id: 1,
            description: 'my event 1'
        }];
    var mySource2 = [{
            title : 'Source 2',
            start : moment().add(1, 'days'),
            allDay: false,
            id: 2,
            description: 'my event from 2'
        }];
```

And to attach them to the calendar you can:

### Option a

Define in your calendar not your events, but your sources using `eventSources` as an array of your sources:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    (...)
    eventSources:[mySource1, mySource2],            
});
```

### Option b

Add your source via [add event source method](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/)

```js
.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', mySourceN );
```

### Option c

Updating eventSource:
If you want to add dynamically an event to a specific source, the only way you can achieve it is removing and adding again the source:

So something like:

```js
var myNewEvent: {
        title : 'mytitle',
        start : moment(),
        allDay: false,
        id: 1,
        description: 'my event from source'
    };
mySource.push(myNewEvent);
$('#myCalendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', mySource);
$('#myCalendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', mySource);
```

Honestly, I dislike this C option, but maybe is what you need. There's an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2272&q=add%20to%20source&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars) with this situation in which Adam Shaw propose that solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I totally understand. Indeed, 99% of my events *are* as array sources as you suggest. But I'm also trying to add new events dynamically. I use select/selectHelper to swipe new areas on the calendar and then want to add them to an existing source, not the "sticky" hidden source within fullCalendar.

I'm using renderEvent as documented to add a new event dynamically at that time. Note that the documentation (and the source!) does seem to anticipate calling renderEvent with a new event WITH a source value!

So, regrettably, I think my question still remains!

Comment: I added Solution Option C to my answer. I dislike that solution, but nowadays it's the "only and official" way to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks, Mario - looks like your Option C is the best answer. I guess I'll have to live with the flashing when the source is redrawn or use my fork of fullcalendar with my own fix. Thanks again for taking a look at this for me!